# spring security filter chain : Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

Tags: authentication, spring-security, api-key

I want to protect a web api with an api key.
The idea is to use the Authorization header to pass an apikey with a request and let a spring authentication manager read and verify that apikey.

My current configuration leads to the follwing error:
`Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed`

Here is the setup:

--- WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
ApiKeyHeaderFilter filter = new ApiKeyHeaderFilter(apiKey);    
httpSecurity.csrf()
                .disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .headers()
                .disable()
                .addFilterAfter(filter, RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new ExceptionTranslationFilter(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint()),                                                  filter.getClass())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

--- ApiKeyHeaderFilter

```
public class ApiKeyHeaderFilter extends AuthenticationFilter
{

    public ApiKeyHeaderFilter(String apiKey)
    {
        super(new ApiKeyAuthenticationManager(apiKey), new ApiKeyAuthenticationConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationConverter(AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("authentication converter can not be changed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationManagerResolver(
            AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest> authenticationManagerResolver)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("authentication manager resolver can not be changed.");
    }
}
```

--- ApiKeyAuthenticationManager

```
public class ApiKeyAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager
{
    private final String apiKey;

    public ApiKeyAuthenticationManager(String apiKey)
    {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        authentication.setAuthenticated(apiKey.equals(authentication.getCredentials()));
        if (!authentication.isAuthenticated())
            throw new BadCredentialsException("The API key was not found or not the expected value.");
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

--- ApiKeyAuthenticationConverter

```
public class ApiKeyAuthenticationConverter implements AuthenticationConverter
{
    private static final String API_KEY_PREFIX = "ApiKey ";

    @Override
    public Authentication convert(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        var header = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (nonNull(header) && header.startsWith(API_KEY_PREFIX))
            return new ApiUserAuthentication(header.substring(API_KEY_PREFIX.length()));
        return new ApiUserAuthentication(null);
    }
}
```

--- ApiUserAuthentication

```
public class ApiUserAuthentication implements Authentication
{
    private final String apiKey;
    private boolean isAuthenticated = false;

    public ApiUserAuthentication(String apiKey)
    {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()
    {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials()
    {
        return apiKey;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return "ApiUser";
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal()
    {
        return "ApiUser";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated()
    {
        return isAuthenticated;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated)
    {
        this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

I tried to add the filter at different positions. The only difference it made was, that at one point the Authorization header was not present.
It seems, that I'm missing something essential on how to configure authentication filters.